# How to hide other email address when i send multiple email using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is the controller code for sending email

```
$dataset = $this->Admin_model->getSubscribers();
$outputArray = [];

foreach($dataset as $row) {
    $outputArray[] = $row['subscription_email'];
}

$to_email = implode(', ', $outputArray);

$config = Array(
    'protocol'      => PROTOCOL,
    'smtp_crypto'   => SMTP_CRYPTO,
    'smtp_host'         => SMTP_HOST,
    'smtp_port'         => SMTP_PORT,
    'smtp_user'         => SMTP_USERNAME,
    'smtp_pass'         => SMTP_PASSWORD,
    'smtp_timeout'  => SMTP_TIMEOUT,
    'charset'       => "utf-8",
    'mailtype'      => "html",
    'newline'           => "\r\n",
    'wordwrap'      => TRUE
);

$fromemail  = FROM_EMAIL; //website mail
$name       = FROM_NAME; //website name
$subject    = 'Test';
$message    = ''; //title & 1 image

$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->set_crlf("\r\n");
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from($fromemail, $name);
$this->email->to($to_email);
$this->email->cc("");
$this->email->bcc("");
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);

$this->email->send(); //send email
$this->email->clear();
```

it shows all the recipients email address but i want to hide the other recipient email address when one of the receiver is getting the email

Comment: The only way to be sure is to send one email per recipient

Answer (score 0):

Like @RiggsFolly said, or you can send one email with everyone as a BCC recipient instead of a To, this way no one will see any of the other's emails. The BCC stands for Blind Carbon Copy. That means no one can see who the email is going to.

```
$this->email->to("");
$this->email->cc("");
$this->email->bcc($to_email);
```